# Regarding not getting GNU awk version after creating a docker basic container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a normal docker's container, where I want to run my awk script. So we came to know we have to install GNU awk in it too, so could you please let me know if there any way we could get it in container itself(which creating os image) rather than installing it separately:

I apologies if I missed something here as I am new to this technology.

Comment: you could start `FROM` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) a minimal image like https://hub.docker.com/r/mor1/gawk/, or just `apt-get install gawk` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: What image are you using for the container?

Comment: May be install minimal `alpine` docker image and install `gnu awk` on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of gawk-installed docker images publicly available. You may directly use one of them. A few examples: [atarumix/gawk5-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/r/atarumix/gawk5-alpine) [algas/gawk](https://hub.docker.com/r/algas/gawk). I have to note that most (if not all) are not actively maintained.

You may create a `Dockerfile` and install `gawk`. Although you mentioned you do not want to have a separate install, it is pretty easy. Consider this for example:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache gawk ffmpeg
```

If you do not want to use that docker file, you may push the generated image to an image repository. After you push the image, you shall be able to use the image directly. Details of push can be found at [push reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/).